# How could I use list elements for lamba loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use filter and lamba to filter the elements in `names`.
But everytime I could only put one string.
I want to use each elements from `jen` to filter the elements in `names` as a loop way.

How to make it? please advise me
Here is my code:

```
names = ['Toy','Men','Moi','Cano']
jen = ['en','oi','ok','no','t']

filtered_names = filter(lambda item: 'en' in item, names)

for item in filtered_names:
    print(item)
```

My output for now is:

Men

I want it could be:

```
for x in jen
filtered_names = filter(lambda item: x in item, names)
```

And hope it could like a loop, so that I don't need to change every element inside `filter(lambda item: x in item, names)`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in a loop then try this:

```
from functools import partial

def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word

names = ['Toy','Men','Moi','Cano']
jen = ['en','oi','ok','no','t']


for i in jen:
    print(f"Scanning for {i}")
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=i), names)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
Scanning for en
Men
Scanning for oi
Moi
Scanning for ok
Scanning for no
Cano
Scanning for t
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me for my another question :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
filtered_names = filter(lambda item: any(x in item for x in jen), names)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
filtered_names = [item for item in names if any(x in item for x in jen)]
```

Comment: The list comprehension is about 20% faster on my machine.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Now the output is :
Men
Moi
Cano
| But how can i identify which output is resulted from which elements?

Comment: You can't using `any`, it doesn't give you information on which elements matched. You can use something like my answer though.